# Where to find core eclipse plugins for the Hello World sample plugin project?

Tags: eclipse

I have eclipse oxygen installed and I'm trying to create the sample HelloWorld plugin project.

The plugin project has dependencies on core plugins from the org.eclipse.core/ui/jface etc libraries and I can't find them anywhere on my local machine so that I can add them to my target platform and have them resolved.

Where are these jars supposed to be?